# CoreLocation for OS X using iFrame Google Maps can't select "Map, Satellite, Terrain" as default

Tags: xcode, macos, google-maps, iframe, core-location

I have been modifying the code here: [WhereIsMyMac](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/09/whereismymac-snow-leopard-corelocation.html) to try and get a better understanding of CoreLocation for OS X. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to modify the template HTML file to force a "Maps" view - my frame defaults to "Satellite View"

Here is the relevant line:

```
src="http://maps.google.com/maps?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=%f,%f&amp;spn=%f,%f&amp;t=h&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed"
```

Perhaps I'm not using the proper search terms to find the answer on my own, but I cannot find out how to force this into "Map View"

Any pointers would be a great help. I know this is a simple question - but I cannot find the answer.

Comment: @REDBLUETHING 's answer is correct the one marked as a solution has a broken link. Sorry, cannot upvote yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the *t* parameter to set the map type:

> t= Map Type. The available options are
>   "m" map, "k" satellite, "h" hybrid,
>   "p" terrain.

So from your source:

```
src="http://maps.google.com/maps?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=%f,%f&amp;spn=%f,%f&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed"
```

Answer (score 0):

solution:

http://mapki.com/index.php?title=Google_Map_Parameters